# Not able to play avi files using mediaelement.js plugin

Tags: php, html, mediaelement.js

I have been using the `mediaelement.js` `plugin` in my website.I have been playing `video formats` like `mp4` etc.But I cannot play videos with `avi` format.I would like to know if `mediaelement.js` does support playing `avi` videos or is there some other way by which i could play videos with `avi` format.Really hoping if someone could help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVI files aren't any good for streaming videos. The main reason for this is, the index block - which is needed for seeking - is located at the end of AVI files, thus requiring the file to be completely buffered locally before the user can seek specific positions in the video.

For this reason, `mediaelement.js` doesn't support AVI files. And that's also why you should always convert videos to h.264 MP4 or FLV for streaming (yes, those formats have the index at the beginning, so they're a lot better for streaming).